# How can I lock a function for a caller and return other callers immediately?

Tags: thread-safety, locking

I have a time consuming code that is not thread safe, and I want to make sure only one caller gets to use it at one time, and other callers should just get an error or whatever, basically return immediately.

This is my approach in C#:

```
public ErrorCodes SomeFunction()
{
  lock(_lock)
  {
    if(_beingUsed)
      return ErrorCodes.BeingUsed;

    _beingUsed = true;
  }

  // Time consuming code that is not thread safe.

  lock(_lock)
  {
    _beingUsed = false;
  }
}
```

But I couldn't find anything similar or a different solution to my problem. Is it good enough? Do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple improvements for your approach.

1) You need to add `try-finally` block to set `_beingUsed = false` guaranteed. Otherwise if time consuming code will throw an exception then no one caller will be able to run this code.

2) Since the code that is below the first lock is available only for one caller I don't see need for the second lock.

Here is improved code:

```
public ErrorCodes SomeFunction()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if(_beingUsed)
          return ErrorCodes.BeingUsed;

        _beingUsed = true;
    }

    // here can enter only one caller
    try
    {
        // Time consuming code that is not thread safe.
        return ErrorCodes.OK;
    }
    finally
    {
        _beingUsed = false;
    }
}
```

If the performance is very critical you can consider the lock-free approach:

```
int _flag = 0;
public ErrorCodes SomeFunction()
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _flag, 1) == 0)
    {
        // here can enter only one caller
        try
        {
            //process long operation
            return ErrorCodes.OK;
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _flag, 0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //immediately return
        return ErrorCodes.BeingUsed;
    }
}
```

But this code looks more complex and requires understanding of lock-free programming.